# RxJava check condition with delay

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I need to request a report from remote service.
According to its API I need to do it in 3 steps:
1. Submit a request for report collecting(as a response I get reportId).
2. Check report status until it becomes 'done' with some delay(e.g. 10 seconds).
3. And finally get the report by id.

So, the question is following: is there any way using RxJava API check a predicate function until it returns true with some delay?

The most appropriate operator I could find was 'takeUntil' and code was something like this:

```
Observable.just(request)
            .map(this::submitAndGetId)
            .takeUntil(this::reportIsDone)
            .map(this::getReport)
```

But I couldn't find a way to specify the delay between status checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap` and `interval`:

```
Observable
  .just(request)
  .map(this::submitAndGetId)
  .flatMap(id -> 
    Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .filter(n -> reportIsDone(id))
        .map(n -> id)
        .first()
  )
  .map(this::getReport);
```

For a capped exponential backoff on the retries:

```
Observable<Long> retries = 
  Observable
    .just(1, 2, 4, 8, 16)
    .concatWith(Observable.just(30).repeat())
    .flatMap(n -> Observable.timer(n, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

Observable
  .just(request)
  .map(this::submitAndGetId)
  .flatMap(id -> 
     retries
        .filter(n -> reportIsDone(id))
        .map(n -> id)
        .first()
  )
  .map(this::getReport);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. One more related questions I have: do you know whether it's possible to increase the delay between consequent retries? For example first - 1 seconds, 2nd - 2, 3rd - 4 and so on.

Comment: Yes, I've added it to the answer.